# Searching for voters by address

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, search

I have 3 tables, 1 where voters information is stored, 2 where their address is stored and 3 where voter `id`s are matched with address `id`s. I thought this approach was best as several voters can occupy the same address.

Now I have Query that selects all the voters on a given street / road. Although it works, I'm not sure if I should be using `joins` or keep using `where`, and if `locate` is the best way to search a field.

```
SELECT `voter_name`, `address_full`
FROM `tr_voter`, `tr_voter_address`, `tr_voter_address_assigned`
WHERE tr_voter_address_assigned.voter_id = tr_voter.voter_id 
AND tr_voter_address_assigned.address_id = tr_voter_address.address_id 
AND LOCATE('insert street name here', `address_full`) 
ORDER BY `address_2`, `address_1`
LIMIT 0 , 200
```

`address_full` is the full address, where each component is broken down into `address_1`, `address_2` etc. This does mean however, in some cases with house names, that a street may be stored in 1 2 or 3, so searching the full field seemed the full proof way to do it.

Voter Table

```
`voter_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`voter_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`voter_number` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `voter_title` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`voter_first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`voter_last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`voter_notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`voter_last_vote_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`voter_entry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`voter_last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`voter_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `number` (`voter_number`)
```

Address Table

```
`address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address_full` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'address name or number',
`address_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_6` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_lat` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address_long` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `address_full` (`address_full`)
```

Assigned Table

```
`assigned_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`voter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`assigned_id`)
```

Comment: Would be nice if you described the schema. (ie tables and attributes marking the keys).

Comment: @LokiAstari - sorry about that, added the structure for you

Comment: The `Assigned Table` is only needed if a voter can live in more than one location. Which is technically possbile. But I would think an over-design as you can only have one registered voting address.

Comment: @LokiAstari you'd be surprised, I did it this way with that in mind, and it is indeed possible, for example uni students to be registered with uni and home address, rare as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Assuming you need the "Assigned Table" to support the many to many relationship of a voter to address.

```
`assigned_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`voter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`assigned_id`)
```

You don't need `assigned_id`. Remove this. The primary key is `(voter_id, address_id)`

Comment: thank you, didnt know yer could have two fields as primary